# Regex change comma to point only in certain lines mac terminal

Tags: regex, macos, replace, terminal

I have many subtitle files and google translate changed some dots in the timecode to commas. Is there a way using the Terminal to replace all commas in the timecode with dots? I think its possible to address all lines `-->`

Here's a sample of the text.

```
WEBVTT

00:00,000 --> 00:03,000
Der perfekte Case sozusagen war,

00:03,000 --> 00:06,000
dass man in der gleichen Stadt wohnt, befreundet ist,

00:06,000 --> 00:08,000
sich 6 Monate nicht gesehen hat 

....
```

I have tried the following, but it changed all commas of course:

```
sed -i '' 's/,/./g' *.vtt
```

Thanks a lot!
Vinni

Comment: Lines containing `-->` do not seem to have commas.

Comment: sorry, i used a wrong example. I updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `sed` to replace comma by dot in lines containing `-->`:

```
sed '/-->/s/,/./g' file
WEBVTT

00:00.000 --> 00:03.000
Der perfekte Case sozusagen war,

00:03.000 --> 00:06.000
dass man in der gleichen Stadt wohnt, befreundet ist,

00:06.000 --> 00:08.000
sich 6 Monate nicht gesehen hat

....
```